# Azure DevOps Release pipeline for Databricks notebook

Tags: azure-devops, databricks, azure-databricks, databricks-cli

I am creating a Azure DevOps Release Pipeline for Databricks notebooks deployment.

I have written below code in powershell activity but its not working.

Requesting some pointer here.

```
# Variables
$workspaceUrl = "https://<databricks-instance>"
$personalAccessToken = "<databricks-personal-access-token>"
$notebookPath = "/notebooks/my_notebook.ipynb"
$targetEnvironment = "UAT"

# Authenticate with Databricks CLI
databricks configure --token
databricks configure --token "$personalAccessToken" --url "$workspaceUrl"

# Deploy Notebook to UAT Environment
databricks workspace import -l "$notebookPath" -o "/$targetEnvironment$notebookPath"
```

Comment: What does "not working" mean? Please be explicit with the issues you're encountering when asking for help.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to configure CLI explicitly, it's just enough to expose workspace URL as `DATABRICKS_HOST` environment variable, and personal access token as `DATABRICKS_TOKEN` environment variable - then CLI will automatically pickup them. See [documentation](https://docs.databricks.com/archive/dev-tools/cli/index.html#set-up-authentication-using-a-databricks-personal-access-token) for full list of supported variables.

It's also not recommended to specify PAT directly in the code, but instead it's better to put it & workspace URL into variables and refer from the pipeline, like this ([full example](https://github.com/alexott/databricks-nutter-repos-demo/blob/master/azure-pipelines.yml#L74)):

```yaml
    - script: |
        echo "Checking out the $(branchName) branch"
        databricks repos update --path $(STAGING_DIRECTORY) --branch "$(branchName)"
      env:
        DATABRICKS_HOST: $(DATABRICKS_HOST)
        DATABRICKS_TOKEN: $(DATABRICKS_TOKEN)
      displayName: 'Update Staging project'
```